# Surf function won't graph 2D Gaussian

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to graph a simple 2D Gaussian in MATLAB using the surf function, but I'm getting an error saying that the last value in surf must be a matrix and not a vector. I don't understand how to graph the function then as every other example I've found while searching has had the third value as a vector. I feel as if I'm completely off base here with the surf function. Any ideas?

```
amp = 10;
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
sigmaX = 10
sigmaY = 10
X = 1:1:100;
Y = 1:1:100;
Z = amp*exp(-(X-x0).^2/(2*sigmaX^2)+(Y-y0).^2/(2*sigmaY^2));
disp(size(Z))
surf(X, Y, Z);
```

**Edit**

When I plot this using @Suever's answer, I get something that doesn't look like a Gaussian at all.

[Here's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECH33.png)

```
amp = 1;
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
sigmaX = 1;
sigmaY = 1;
%X = 1:1:100;
%Y = 1:1:100;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:.1:3);
%Z = X .* exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);
Z = amp*exp(-(X-x0).^2/(2*sigmaX^2)+(Y-y0).^2/(2*sigmaY^2));
surf(X, Y, Z);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used `X` and `Y` to define a 2D domain over which you would like to compute your gaussian. If you want `Z` to be a function of `X` and `Y`, you need to define `Z` for *all permutations* of `X` and `Y`. If you don't provide a matrix of `Z` values, MATLAB has no idea how to create a surface over the `X` `Y` ranges you've provided.

You can create all permutations of `X` and `Y` using `meshgrid` and then compute `Z` over this entire domain. Then you will be able to display the result with `surf`.

```
amp = 10; x0 = 50; y0 = 50; sigmaX = 10; sigmaY = 10;

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:100, 1:100);

% Z as you had it written (see correct version below)
Z = amp*exp(-(X-x0).^2./(2*sigmaX^2)+(Y-y0).^2./(2*sigmaY^2));

surf(X, Y, Z);
```

**Update**

Your equation for the 2D Gaussian is wrong. The `-` sign should be *outside* of the addition of the two components. The way that you had it written, you negated the X-component and then added to the Y component.

```
Z = amp*exp(-((X-x0).^2./(2*sigmaX^2)+(Y-y0).^2./(2*sigmaY^2)));
```

[image]

Comment: Got it working! But now my graph looks nothing like a 2D Gaussian (image in OP). Any ideas?

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez Updated with the *correct* equation. Also if you're going to change the problem add to your initial question rather than completely replacing it

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you for your help!